# HTTP 500 error when calling /apps/{accessTokens}/de-authenticate with an access_token argument in GET

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

For almost all API calls, I pass both my key and my access_token.  This doesn't exactly make sense for the "de-authenticate" endpoint, as the access token is already in the URL.  Passing one anyway yields a rather unhelpful 500 error, although the user is successfully deauthenticated.

I've put together a quick page to show the error:

http://withoutthesarcasm.com/stackapps/bug/

The "error" link will de-authenticate with the access_token passed as a GET parameter as well as in the URL, and the "OK" link will de-authenticate without passing the access_token as a GET parameter.

Probably a low severity bug, but I thought I'd report it anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this has been deployed.

The error was in updating the throttle after the access token was invalidated, so now the token lives on from the perspective of the request making it until it completes.  It is, however, destroyed immediately from the perspective of any other requests at the time.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the fix.  Should I pass the access_token as part of the GET parameters, so as to get the request properly tracked from a throttle perspective?  Or can you guys do this from the access_token in the URL?  I don't think it matters that much (throttle-wise, it's a tiny amount of the total requests) but I thought I'd ask anyhow.

Comment: @agent86 - pass it as a parameter, for simplicity and consistency throttling doesn't look for anything other than `?access_token=...`.

Comment: Sounds good, will do.